# Set console font size in fullscreen mode

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, windows-xp, console-application

I use [SetConsoleDisplayMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028(v=vs.85).aspx) to switch the console into fullscreen mode. It is 80x25, centered in the middle with quite a small font, which I'd like to enlarge.

I still work on WinXP, so [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx) is not an option for me. I found [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/) which describes some undocumented functions including `SetConsoleFont()`. They work great: the `GetNumberOfConsoleFonts()` returns 9 usable fonts on my system and I can pick some, however under fullscreen 0 font were found, which means it is not supported.

I also tried to create shortcut to the program and set the console there, but there's no fullscreen option and after switching to fullscreen all font settings are discarded.

I'd like to convince the screen to show nice big text font, just like in sci-fi movies or in good old BIOS assembly coding. Is it possible under XP?

Comment: Downvote? Please tell me what's wrong with my question: I made quite an effort to solve it and I'm not going to mess it with reasons why XP. If you even bothered to visit the link, you may learn that there is still missing lots of functionality even in current version of windows. You could at least comment why the fonts are not supported in fullscreen mode :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full-screen console mode switches the display adapter into 80x25 VGA text mode.

Thus font-rendering is completely different.  In a normal console window the font is rendered using GDI; in full-screen mode Windows writes a character code to the display buffer and the hardware renders the font.

VGA supports loadable fonts and Windows uses this feature to support its different language versions.  I don't remember if the font is fixed by the language version of Windows or if its chosen to match the current code page.  (Full-screen mode doesn't work on x64 and I don't have a 32-bit system handy to try it.)

I'm not aware of you getting any kind of choice in the VGA font used, though there's probably some mileage in overwriting the VGA fonts in the Fonts directory.  Though obviously this isn't something you'd want to be doing in production.

Finally, it might be possible to change the font using an actual DOS app!  I know Windows NT traps some video-related IOs and passes them through to the hardware.  This isn't much use though.

Comment: Hmm... I am tempted to install Turbo C 3.0 and do some retro programming ;-) It was so fast, easy and fun... I'm really tempted!

Comment: @JanTuroň Even it if does work in DOS, you'd lose the changes as soon as the DOS program exited.  I didn't make this very clear.  That said, it might be fun.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to write out `GetLastError()`? My opinion is that this will not be working on windows 7 or later.
Maybe you could try this: `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601`

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I use `_WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` (XP). `GetLastError()` returns 1007 in fullscreen *The requested operation cannot be performed in full-screen mode.* Sad, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! One thing you could try is to disable the display adapters using C++, that will change your resolution and maybe then you may be able to switch to the fullscreen mode. Before program quitting, enable the display adapters again.